# Zipcodes to geo_points translator for Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with `zipcode` as a field (string). I'd like to make it an object with the following properties:

- `value` - to hold the string zipcode itself
- `geo` - of type `geo_point` to hold the center of the zipcode location

I have a CSV file with a mapping between zipcodes to lat,lon and I thought to use [Ingest Node's Pipelines](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) to automatically add the geo-location. I don't want the client to have to do it, or hold the zip->geo mapping table.

I couldn't find any equivalent to Logstash's "translate" filter. I'd like something that can receive a mapping file (CSV/YAML/JSON/ I don't care) and translates a field's value according to the mapping.

Does anyone know of an elegant way to translate field values?